# Insert a variable in a string to a random place?

Tags: perl

We have a string that has a length of 20 characters.

We have a number, that is random, ex.: 6

We have a variable, ex.: $var="%"

**How can we insert a variable to the 6th place in the string?**

Example:

INPUT: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

OUTPUT: aaaaa%aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

echo INPUT | **MAGIC** > OUTPUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to do what you want:

```
mystring="This is a test"
inject="____"
randomnumber=4 # determined to be random by fair die roll

echo ${mystring::$randomnumber}${inject}${mystring:$randomnumber}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this with `perl`:

```
echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | var=% perl -lpe 's/^.{5}\K/$ENV{var}/e'
```

Another way with `perl`:

```
echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | var=% perl -lpe 'substr $_, 5, 0, $ENV{var}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with `perl`, but `sed`, if anyone is interested.

```
INPUT="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
random_number="6"
var="%"

echo ${INPUT} | sed -e "s/./${var}/${random_number}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your $var a perl variable that you already have access to, or is it a shell variable?

For this particular case, I'd probably prefer to use `substr`.

```
$ echo "123456789" | perl -lpe 'substr $_, 5, 0, "insert"'
12345insert6789
```

Comment: shelll variable